# How to run a command with %?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am trying to run command `git log origin/master..HEAD --format=format:"%H"` in python as below but running into below error,I tried to escape `%` but that doesn't fix the error, any idea how to fix it?

```
def runCmd2(cmd):
    logger.info("Running command %s"%cmd)
    proc = Popen(cmd ,universal_newlines = True, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    (output, error) = proc.communicate()
    return output.strip(),error.strip()

def get_local_commits():
    """Get local commits """
    branch = "master"
    cmd = "git log origin/%s..HEAD  --format=format:\"%H\" "%(branch)
    output,error = runCmd2(cmd)
    return output,error
```

ERROR:-

```
  File "/Users/gnakkala/jitsuin/wifi-ci/enable_signing.py", line 45, in get_local_commits
    cmd = "git log origin/%s..HEAD  --format=format:\"%H\" "%(branch)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To escape % you double it, using %%

```
branch = "master"
cmd = 'git log origin/%s..HEAD  --format=format:"%%H"' % branch
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using the shell *at all* here, which makes the problem go away.

```
def runCmd2(cmd: list[str):
    logger.info("Running command %s"%(' '.join(cmd))
    proc = Popen(cmd, universal_newlines=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    (output, error) = proc.communicate()
    return output.strip(),error.strip()

def get_local_commits():
    """Get local commits """
    branch = "master"
    cmd = ["git", "log", "origin/{}..HEAD".format(branch), '--format=format:%H']
    output,error = runCmd2(cmd)
    return output,error
```

Answer (score -1):

### % interpolation is outdated

#### use f-strings instead!

```py
def runCmd2(cmd):
    logger.info(f'Running command {cmd}')
    proc = Popen(cmd ,universal_newlines = True, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    (output, error) = proc.communicate()
    return output.strip(),error.strip()

def get_local_commits():
    """Get local commits """
    branch = "master"
    cmd = f'git log origin/{branch}..HEAD  --format=format:\"{'%H'}\"'
    output,error = runCmd2(cmd)
    return output,error
```

Comment: % interpolation is not "outdated", it's here to stay.  And your code has syntax errors.

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/

Comment: where are the errors? @wim

Comment: The PEP you just linked literally says "_This PEP does not propose to remove or deprecate any of the existing string formatting mechanisms._".

Comment: scroll a little bit it literally describes OP's issue in the Rationale section. "
This PEP is driven by the desire to have a simpler way to format strings in Python. **The existing ways of formatting are either error prone, inflexible, or cumbersome.**"

Comment: It sounds like f-string are the error prone one, since you're the one with a syntax error ... ;)

Comment: the only syntax error is in the fact that **you're** the interpreter @wim